# Couchbase Lite Android - Populating a ListView in a memory friendly way

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I'm used to using Loader's and CursorAdapter's in Android.  Looking at Couchbase-Lite for Android, I can't readily see a way to populate a ListView in what I would consider to be a memory friendly fashion.

Looking at the code in their example app here:
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/GrocerySync-Android/blob/master/GrocerySync-Android/src/main/java/com/couchbase/grocerysync/MainActivity.java

```
protected void startCBLite() throws Exception {
    manager = new Manager(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    //install a view definition needed by the application
    database = manager.getDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
    com.couchbase.lite.View viewItemsByDate = database.getView(String.format("%s/%s", designDocName, byDateViewName));
    viewItemsByDate.setMap(new Mapper() {
        @Override
        public void map(Map<String, Object> document, Emitter emitter) {
            Object createdAt = document.get("created_at");
            if (createdAt != null) {
                emitter.emit(createdAt.toString(), null);
            }
        }
    }, "1.0");


    startLiveQuery(viewItemsByDate);

    startSync();

}

private void startSync() {

    URL syncUrl;
    try {
        syncUrl = new URL(SYNC_URL);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    Replication pullReplication = database.createPullReplication(syncUrl);
    pullReplication.setContinuous(true);

    Replication pushReplication = database.createPushReplication(syncUrl);
    pushReplication.setContinuous(true);

    pullReplication.start();
    pushReplication.start();

    pullReplication.addChangeListener(this);
    pushReplication.addChangeListener(this);

}

private void startLiveQuery(com.couchbase.lite.View view) throws Exception {

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = showLoadingSpinner();

    if (liveQuery == null) {

        liveQuery = view.createQuery().toLiveQuery();

        liveQuery.addChangeListener(new LiveQuery.ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(LiveQuery.ChangeEvent event) {
                displayRows(event.getRows());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        liveQuery.start();

    }

}

private void displayRows(QueryEnumerator queryEnumerator) {

    final List<QueryRow> rows = getRowsFromQueryEnumerator(queryEnumerator);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            itemListViewAdapter = new GrocerySyncListAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    R.layout.grocery_list_item,
                    R.id.label,
                    rows
            );
            itemListView.setAdapter(itemListViewAdapter);
            itemListView.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);
            itemListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(MainActivity.this);

        }
    });
}


private List<QueryRow> getRowsFromQueryEnumerator(QueryEnumerator queryEnumerator) {
    List<QueryRow> rows = new ArrayList<QueryRow>();
    for (Iterator<QueryRow> it = queryEnumerator; it.hasNext();) {
        QueryRow row = it.next();
        rows.add(row);
    }
    return rows;
}
```

and here:
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/GrocerySync-Android/blob/master/GrocerySync-Android/src/main/java/com/couchbase/grocerysync/GrocerySyncListAdapter.java

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View itemView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ...
   QueryRow row = list.get(position);
   Document document = row.getDocument();
   ...
}
```

The query returns an enumerator, which then is looped over to create ArrayList, which is then passed to the query adapter. This is all done on the UI thread.

That's probably fine for a simple grocery app demo, but what if I have 20,000 documents in my database, and 18,000 come back in response to my query?

Comment: I found the same. The QueryEnumerator contains a List<QueryRow>
https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-java-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/couchbase/lite/QueryEnumerator.java

Answer (score 0):

look at TodoLite Android sample proect. In that check out TaskAdapter. That handles that situation by using queryEnumertor directly into BaseAdapter
Below is link to MainActivity which contains TaskAdapter Class

https://github.com/couchbaselabs/ToDoLite-Android/blob/master/ToDoLite/src/main/java/com/couchbase/todolite/MainActivity.java